# I have trouble inserting and deleting rows in my SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert

This is my code for the insert, I got *textboxes* on my *form* and I write something inside but when pressing the button with executes the code below it shows an error by the (`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`)

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::dotasuka.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);

try
{
    cn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Heroes (Heroname, Attacktype, patribute, role, role2, role3) VALUES (@Heroname, @Attacktype, @patribute, @role, @role2, @role3)";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Heroname", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attacktype", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patribute", textBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", textBox4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role2", textBox5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role3", textBox6.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    textBox1.Clear(); textBox2.Clear(); 
    textBox3.Clear(); textBox4.Clear(); 
    textBox5.Clear(); textBox6.Clear();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    cn.Close();
}
```

The second code snippet is my update code which shows same an error when trying to execute, same error by the `execute non query`

```
SqlDataReader reader = null;
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::dotasuka.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);

SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Heroes ", cn);

cn.Open();

reader = sda.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    object Heroname = reader["heroname"];

    listBox1.Items.Add(Heroname.ToString());
}

reader.Close();

cn.Close();
```

Please I need help and as quick as someone can, ty!

Comment: "An error"? Please always report (and read carefully while you're at it) the **exact** error message you're getting.

Comment: Check my answer, If that helped for you, do not forget to select It as correct answer.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0):

I think you receive this error, that because you using [reserved word](https://www.drupal.org/node/141051) `Role` you should place It in brackets `[]`.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Heroes (Heroname, Attacktype,patribute,[role],role2,role3) VALUES (@Heroname, @Attacktype,@patribute,@role,@role2,@role3)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to avoid that method of passing parameters, with

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Heroname", textBox1.Text);
```

you didn't specify `datatype` and `length`, that's correct ADO.NET will guess them but this is not happens always, instead of that try this method:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Heroname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox1.Text;
```

for all of your parameters.

Comment: You are welcome, if it was helpful you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark in the left side of answer.

Answer (score 0):

Was it a null reference exception?

Reading your code, I think you need to change `SqlDataReader reader = null;` to `SqlDataReader reader = new SqlDataReader;`

Answer (score 0):

```
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::dotasuka.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);


        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Heroes (heroname,attacktype,patribute,role,role2,role3) Values (@heroname,@attacktype,@patribute,@role,@role2,@role3) ", cn);
            cn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@heroname", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attacktype", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patribute", textBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", textBox4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role2", textBox5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role3", textBox6.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();

        }
```

1. This code worked now, inside my form i added a listbox and it does show the added row with its values! But closing form and checking inside database, it doesnt show that row? Whats wrong?

Comment: well it means, you passed the value to the listbox from the textbox, but the values of the textbox to your data type in your database might have conflicts,